# Can you reset a password for a restricted profile?

Tags: password, android-device-manager, restricted-profiles

I have a restricted profile that is asking for a password, and it is not taking it. As the owner, I would like to be able to reset this password.

Long Story: The restricted profile is my son's. Since it was setup we have always used a pattern to unlock. I made the mistake of locking his tablet remotely using Android Device Manger, and setting a password. That password did not work on his profile. I switched to my owner account, and it worked fine. Now, however, his profile is asking for a password to be typed, and nothing works. I assume he set it to something he has forgotten since he has used pattern lock for a long time. ADM seems to have reset the screen lock to password instead of pattern on the profile without resetting the password itself.

So, any way to fix this short of deleting and creating a new restricted profile?

Comment: you can login to ur account right? why dont to reset device from there?

Comment: There is the nuclear option. Wipe out his profile and start over, but then he loses all his data. I'm trying to do something short of that.

Answer (score 3):

I spent three hours on the phone with Google yesterday for the same issue. They said there is no way to reset the password.  They said I have to delete and add the user back, losing all data, pictures, game progress, etc.  There is also no way to prevent a child from setting a password.  Clearly the people at Google have not thought this through. It is definitely not a "kids mode".

Comment: There are answers that suggest you can hack the sqlite database to change the login settings. I'm in the OPs position. If I know I can stash my daughter's "stuff" I'll be heading for the nuclear option by deleting and recreating her profile. It really shouldn't take proficiency with adb to manage an android device in a family environment!